# ActionListener call blocks MouseClick event

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, mouseclick-event

I have a window with a MenuItem "maddbound3" with the following ActionListener:

```
maddbound3.addActionListener
(
    new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        { 
            menu_addbound3();
        } 
    }
);
```

When the menu is clicked this listener calls menu_addbound3() below:

```
void menu_addbound3()
{
    while(getEditMode() != EditMode.NONE)
    {
        System.out.println("!... " + getEditMode());

        synchronized(this)
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A MouseClicked event alters the value of the edit mode and issues a notifyAll() so that the while loop should exit. However, tests have shown that when the system is running through the while loop, the MouseClicked event never occurs on clicking the mouse.

Does the ActionListener block the MouseClicked event? How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: If you are talking about a different MouseEvent, then yes the while loop is bloking the EDT so that second MouseEvent will never be triggered. Maybe we could be of more help if you explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't have a `while(true)` on the Swing event thread, and likewise don't call `wait()` on the Swing event thread -- you'll freeze the whole GUI making it completely unresponsive. You need to understand that the main Swing event thread or "event dispatch thread" is responsible for all Swing drawing and user interaction, and so if you tie it up with long-running or freezing code, you lock your entire GUI.

Instead, change the state of your program -- perhaps by setting a variable or two, and have the behavior of your program depend on this state. If you need more specific advice, please tell us what behavior you're trying to achieve, and we can perhaps give you a better way of doing it.

For more on the Swing event thread, please read: [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

**Edit**
You state:

> When the user clicks the menu item I want to obtain information via a series of "discrete" mouse clicks from the window. Hence, on clicking the menu, the user would be prompted to "select a point in the window". So, what I need is for my ActionListener function (menu_addbound3) to then wait for a mouse click. Hence the wait/notify setup. A mouse click changes the edit_mode and notifyAll() causes the wait in the while loop to exit which then causes the while loop to exit and I can then prompt for my next bit of information within the menu_addbound3 function, repeating this as as I need to.

Thanks for the clarification, and now I can definitely tell you that you are doing it wrong, that you most definitely do not want to use the while loop or wait or notify.  There are many ways to solve this issue, one could be to use some boolean or enum variables to give the program a state and then alter its behavior depending on the state. Your EditMode enum can be used in the MouseListener to let it know that its active, and then you could also give the MouseListener class a boolean variable windowPointSelected, set to false, and then only set it true after the first click has been made.

**Edit 2**
For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ProgState extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 400;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private static final Color EDIT_COLOR = Color.red;
   private EditMode editMode = EditMode.NONE;
   private boolean firstPointSelected = false;
   private JMenuBar jMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
   private JTextField firstPointField = new JTextField(15);
   private JTextField secondPointField = new JTextField(15);

   public ProgState() {
      add(firstPointField);
      add(secondPointField);

      JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
      menu.add(new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Edit") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            setEditMode(EditMode.EDITING);
            setFirstPointSelected(false);
         }
      }));
      jMenuBar.add(menu);

      addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

         @Override
         public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mEvt) {
            if (getEditMode() == EditMode.EDITING) {
               Point p = mEvt.getPoint();
               String pStr = String.format("[%d, %d]", p.x, p.y);
               if (!isFirstPointSelected()) {
                  firstPointField.setText(pStr);
                  setFirstPointSelected(true);
               } else {
                  secondPointField.setText(pStr);
                  setEditMode(EditMode.NONE);
               }
            }
         }

      });
   }

   public void setEditMode(EditMode editMode) {
      this.editMode = editMode;

      Color c = editMode == EditMode.NONE ? null : EDIT_COLOR;
      setBackground(c);
   }

   public EditMode getEditMode() {
      return editMode;
   }

   public void setFirstPointSelected(boolean firstPointSelected) {
      this.firstPointSelected = firstPointSelected;
   }

   public boolean isFirstPointSelected() {
      return firstPointSelected;
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   public JMenuBar getJMenuBar() {
      return jMenuBar;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      ProgState progState = new ProgState();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("EditMode");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(progState);
      frame.setJMenuBar(progState.getJMenuBar());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

enum EditMode {
   NONE, EDITING
}
```

Comment: @pbs: please explain in greater detail as I still don't understand your current code set up or main problem. Why do you even think you need the while loops, because in all likelihood you don't. Also, don't mix AWT components (Canvas) with Swing (JFrame), unless there is a pressing need. Stick with all-Swing if possible.

Comment: When the user clicks the menu item I want to obtain information via a series of "discrete" mouse clicks from the window. Hence, on clicking the menu, the user would be prompted to "select a point in the window". So, what I need is for my ActionListener function (menu_addbound3) to then wait for a mouse click. Hence the wait/notify setup. A mouse click changes the edit_mode and notifyAll() causes the wait in the while loop to exit which then causes the while loop to exit and I can then prompt for my next bit of information within the menu_addbound3 function, repeating this as as I need to.

Comment: @pbs: yeah, you need to re-think how event-driven programming works. See Edit 1.

Comment: I can use this article to create my own thread: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/index.shtml , however, since I am new to concurrent programming I will read the articles you mention.

Comment: @pbs: again, creating a new thread for this is the wrong way to solve your problem. Please don't do this.

Comment: So I'm guessing I should change the program state when the menu is clicked. The MouseClicked event would then do different things for different states.

Comment: @pbs: an example of a simple state machine. Please run my code to see how it's MouseListener's behavior can change due to enum and boolean variable states.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12565/discussion-between-hovercraft-full-of-eels-and-pbs)

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion it seems that having your class assume a number of states is the best way to proceed. We can achieve this by *one or more* enum variables. The reason I found this so hard to grasp initially is that I couldn't see the benefit of having all of ones code in the MouseClicked function. This is ugly and unmanageable at best.

However, using multiple enums and splitting processing into a number of external functions, we do indeed achieve a nice system for what we want.